# Increase number until mets condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

I have creation of tenant

Here is code

```
var tenant = new Tenant(tenancyName, name)
{
    IsActive = isActive,
    EditionId = editionId,
    SubscriptionEndDateUtc = subscriptionEndDate?.ToUniversalTime(),
    IsInTrialPeriod = isInTrialPeriod,
    ConnectionString = connectionString.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()
        ? null
        : SimpleStringCipher.Instance.Encrypt(connectionString)
};

await CreateAsync(tenant);
await _unitOfWorkManager.Current.SaveChangesAsync(); //To get new tenant's id.
```

`tenancyName` can be duplicated

So for checking it I use this condition

```
if (await TenantRepository.FirstOrDefaultAsync(t => t.TenancyName == tenant.TenancyName) != null)
{
    
}
```

I need to add a count to it to be unique.

So for example, if `EugeneTenant` is duplicated, I need to add 2 to it, to be  `EugeneTenant2`,

if EugeneTenant2 is duplicated, add 3 to it, so EugeneTenant3

So it will be autoincremented from 2 until the condition will meet.

I added this code

```
int startNumber = 2;
do
{
    tenant.TenancyName = $"{tenant.TenancyName}{startNumber}";
    tenant.Name = $"{tenant.TenancyName}{startNumber}";
    startNumber++;
}
while (await TenantRepository.FirstOrDefaultAsync(t => t.TenancyName == tenant.TenancyName) != null);
```

But for Example if I have `EugeneTenancy2`, next one I have, `EugeneTenancy23`

How I can do this?

Comment: It's likely  easier to have a separate table/column for storing that number

Answer (score 0):

If you would use a delimiter between the name and the counter (like `EugeneTenancy-2`) then you can get rid of `startNumber` counter.

```
const string Delimiter = "-"; 
var tenancyName = tenant.TenancyName;

string[] parts = tenancyName.Split(Delimiter);
if(parts.Length == 1)
{
   tenancyName = $"{tenancyName}{Delimiter}2";
}
else
{
   int counter = int.Parse(parts[1]);
   tenancyName = $"{tenancyName}{Delimiter}{++counter}";
}

tenant.TenancyName = tenancyName;
tenant.Name = tenancyName;
```

---

Obviously this code is super fragile (`.Length == 1`,`parts[1]`, `int.Parse`, etc.) but you get the idea how to rely on a data, which is already available inside the `TenancyName`.

In other words this is not a robust code, it is created for demonstration purposes only.

---

**UPDATE #1**: If no delimiter is allowed

Then you need to use `TrimStart` instead

```
char[] prefix = originalTenancyName.ToCharArray(); //store outside of the loop

string counterRaw = tenancyName.TrimStart(prefix);
int counter = int.Parse(counterRaw);
```

Comment: But if I don't want delimiter?

Comment: @EugeneSukh I've updated my post accordingly, please revise it

Answer (score 0):

```
var name = "EugeneTenant";
var names = TenantRepository
    .Where(t => t.TenancyName.Contains(tenant.TenancyName))
    .OrderByDescending(t => t.TenancyName)
    .Select(x => x.TenancyName);

if (names.Any()) 
{
    var latest = $"{names.First()}";
    var cnt = $"{Regex.Match(latest, @"\d*$")?.Value}";

    if (int.TryParse(cnt, out int n))
    {
        name = latest.Replace(cnt, $"{n + 1}");
    }
    else
    {
        name += 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Cannot resolve method 'TryParse(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match, out int)', candidates are: bool TryParse(string?, out int) (in struct Int32) bool TryParse(System.ReadOnlySpan<char>, out int) (in struct Int32)

has this error

Comment: i have just edited,

Comment: And as I understand you count from 1

I need to start count from 2

Comment: the 'n' is signed as 1 when the parsing do not succeed it just stays as 1

Comment: For now, it make EugeneTenant1 is EugeneTenant is exits

When I create the next EugeneTenant, it's still make EugeneTenant1, but it's need to be EugeneTenant2